# Sync time across multiple iOS devices to milliseconds level?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, time, ntp

Is it (really) possible to sync time across multiple (not inter-connected) iOS devices to within a few milliseconds accuracy? The only possible solution I (and others, according to Stack Overflow) can think of is sync the devices with a time server(s) over NTP.

---

Multiple sources state:

> NTP is intended to synchronize all participating computers to within a
> few milliseconds of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). It uses the
> intersection algorithm, a modified version of Marzullo's algorithm, to
> select accurate time servers and is designed to mitigate the effects
> of variable network latency. NTP can usually maintain time to within
> tens of milliseconds over the public Internet, and can achieve better
> than one millisecond accuracy in local area networks under ideal
> conditions. Asymmetric routes and network congestion can cause errors
> of 100 ms or more.

---

Can NTP really achieve accuracy within the few milliseconds level?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. You have said that multiple sources say that it is possible with NTP and then ask if is possible. You either believe those statements or not.  Why would one more opinion from Stack Overflow change this?

Comment: @Paulw11 I think personal experience is important and every opinion matters. Having said that, I am also interested to know if there are other alternatives to sync devices over a public network.

Comment: It is a non-trivial problem. A lot of work has gone into NTP and it is used to synchronise literally millions of computers across distributed networks. I doubt you will find anything more accurate outside dedicated hardware solutions